# Jquery Php posting values and getting the result accoridng to the result

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my Jquery and Php file, in which i will post the values in php file through jquery,

### In Simple :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
       var name=$("#txt").val();   
       $.post("test_post.php",
             {name: name}).done(function(data){
              $('#stage').html(data);
               }

          );
      });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt" value="Load Data" />
<input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
```

Here is the .php file.  If the insert was success i should get alert as success else i should get alert as failure.

```
    <?php

 include ('conn.php');
 if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
$q = "INSERT INTO text (name) VALUES ($name)";
if(mysql_query($q))
{
echo 'success'.$q;
}
else
{
echo 'fail'.$q;
}
}
?>
```

And the echo should be displayed in the main page.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Where is your text field?

Comment: @Biz..It is not updated.

Comment: What is actually the issue with this code? Are you facing any errors?

Comment: Actually i am not getting any response. I mean any result even the case is success or failure

Comment: Where is your database connection?

Comment: I included it in conn.php, This is the result i am getting while i echo the query- failINSERT INTO text (name) VALUES (), I mean the value txt is not sending to the source file i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
$q = "INSERT INTO text (name) VALUES ($name)";
```

Here you are not assigning the variable `$name`. So the query will definitely fail.

Change it to:

```
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
  $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
  $q = "INSERT INTO text (name) VALUES ($name)";
  -------------------------
}
```

Comment: @BIz..Glad to help you :)